# DotNetNuke 5.2 - How do I assign a security role to a user from a custom module?

Tags: dotnetnuke

I'm working on a custom module that needs to be able to promote certain users to a particular user security role.

This isn't the primary purpose of the module, it's just a minor feature. (not trying to create a new user management module)

Can somebody please point me in the right direction?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code for this is root/admin/security and root/admin/users

Specfically using the DotNetNuke.Security.Roles.RoleController namespace:

```
DotNetNuke.Security.Roles.RoleController.AddUserRole(int, int, int, System.DateTime)

DotNetNuke.Security.Roles.RoleController.AddUserRole(int PortalID, int UserId, int RoleId, System.DateTime EffectiveDate, System.DateTime ExpiryDate)
```

Answer (score 0):

**1. With PortalSetting, you can use static method**

```
DotNetNuke.Security.Roles.RoleController.AddUserRole(user, role, portalSettings, effectiveDate, expiryDate, userId, notifyUser);
```

**2. Without PortalSetting**

```
var roleController = new DotNetNuke.Security.Roles.RoleController();
roleController.AddUserRole(portalId, userId, roleId, expiryDate);
```